# Vs-code "when clauses" for custom key binding clashes

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, key-bindings

I want to change the default keybinding for the **Notebook: Run All** command in **the Jupyter extension** of **vs code** to ***"shift + Enter"***,

but the problem is that I also have the exact same keybinding for a command called **Run Testcases** in **the CPH JUDGE** extension.

So, I thought that I might need to add some additional **when clauses** in order to make it work,

And here I am...I don't know these specific **" when clauses"**.

Correct me if I am taking it in the wrong direction, and a trivial method is there.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me with this.

[image]

Comment: with `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` you can locate a better context variable to test

Answer (score 0):

One method I found is to use the **"when": "sideBarVisible"** clause in the keybindings.json file to execute the **RunTestcases** command,

because when CPH Judge is used, the sidebar stays open, whereas CPH Judge doesn't work for .ipynb files(Python files in Jupyter notebook).

But now I will have to close my sidebar each time in order to execute the **"Notebook: Run All"** command with **"shift+Enter"** shortcut in Jupyter notebook.

For the time being it's working but Any other efficient way of doing this is highly welcome.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: why post images of your `keybindings.json` file (IT IS A TEXT FILE)

Answer (score 0):

The correct **"when"** clause in this case is **"jupyter.isinteractiveornativeactive"** that is "true when the active editor is a notebook or an interactive window" as stated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Extensibility-for-other-extensions#context-keys-for-keybindings).

Comment: this when clause doesn't seem to be valid anymore